# right continuous representant of L^1 function

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Would someone know if a function in $L^1(\Omega)$ or more generally in $L^p(\Omega)$ must have a right continuous representant. $\Omega$ being a open set of $\mathbb{R}$.

Thankfully,

Comment: what do you mean by right continuous representant?

Comment: I mean a function which is right continuous in the equivalence class up to negligible sets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is No. The following counter example will work.

Consider $f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$ on $\Omega = (0,1)$ and $0$ otherwise. Let $\{r_n \}$ be any enumeration of rationals in the interval $(0, 1)$ and let $g(x) = \sum_1^{\infty} \frac{f(x-r_n)}{2^n}$. Its easy to prove that $g$ is integrable. However, $g$ is discontinuous at every point and unbounded in any interval and it remains so even after modification on any Lebesgue zero set!

Comment: I don't see why it should be discontinuous at every point, can I have any hint about how to look at that

Comment: I allow myself to insist asking you some details, I want to study your counterexemple

Comment: @incas : Try to prove that the $g$ is unbounded in every interval which implies that it is discontinuous at every point! Hope it helps